# Manual call to onListItemCLick

Tags: android, view, adapter

I am using a ListView with a SimpleAdapter.  Once data is populated into it I would like to set the first item in the list.  This can be done by clicking on the list item on the screen.  I want to just call the method directly after I populate the list so that when you see the UI its already done.  My only problem is getting the View from the ListView.  I noticed its children are all null but the SimpleAdapter has items in it.  When I try to get those items they are not Views and I am not able to match the method call of

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

because I cant get the right View.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, by setting it?

Comment: I have a list of items and when you click on one you "set it" in the backend services then do some funky UI stuff to show that it has been set.  Setting it in the backend is not a  problem, its getting the UI to update that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching the solution is not to make a manual call but to override the adapter getView method.  That way I can change the background color and not have to manually call `onListItemClick()`